# RestFul webservices Response for Error code

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I am working on Restful Web Services which give JSON response and i got following output when there is no data for entered id=11

GET Request Failed Request Failed --> Status: (204) Response: {

}

Now I want That response field contain proper message for error code=204 like "invalid request" or "id doesn't exist"

Comment: Why? HTTP status code 204 already means 'No Content', what do you need an additional message for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Jersey or similar JAX-RS framework you can modify your code similar to :

```
return Response.status(204).type("text/plain")
                .entity("Invalid Request!").build();
```

Comment: @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Site getSite() {
        return (Site)siteFacade.find(Integer.parseInt(id));
        
    }

Comment: how to use ur response in @GET

Comment: what technology/framework you are using to construct REST service?

Comment: This is JAX-RS. You can use Jersey which is a reference implementation.