# RestFul WebServices Response for Error code if id does not exist

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I am working on Restful Web Services which give JSON response

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public Site getSite() {
    return (Site)siteFacade.find(Integer.parseInt(id));

}
```

this is my method for getting site info by id

and i got following output when there is no data for entered id=11

```
GET Request Failed Request Failed --> Status: (204) Response: {

}
```

Now I want That response field contain proper message for error code=204 like "invalid request" or "id doesn't exist" where is exact change needed,please help us

Comment: possible duplicate of [RestFul webservices Response for Error code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15111231/restful-webservices-response-for-error-code)

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

Normally if you request something, that is not found you give a 404 to indicate that (that's also in the RESTful spirit):

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public Site getSite() {
  Site site = (Site) siteFacade.find(Integer.parseInt(id));
  if (site == null) {
    return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
  }
  return site;
}
```

If you need a message in the response body you would add something like this, I think:

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public Site getSite() {
  Site site = (Site) siteFacade.find(Integer.parseInt(id));
  if (site == null) {
    return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity("No item with this id found").build();
  }
  return site;
}
```